# PLSQL procedure output having weird blocks

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I am trying to display like first screenshot below and I don't understand the output I am getting (second screenshot).
[image: Output]

[image]

Below is my PLSQL code that I wrote based on my own database. How do I get rid of those weird blocks in my output? Thanks in advance ~

```
create or replace procedure numberOfSupplier (x int := 0 ) is

begin

for QRow in (SELECT REGION.R_NAME,NATION.N_NAME,COUNT(SUPPLIER.S_NATIONKEY) counter
         FROM REGION
         INNER JOIN NATION ON NATION.N_REGIONKEY=REGION.R_REGIONKEY
         INNER JOIN SUPPLIER ON SUPPLIER.S_NATIONKEY=NATION.N_NATIONKEY
         GROUP BY SUPPLIER.S_NATIONKEY,REGION.R_NAME,NATION.N_NAME
         HAVING COUNT(SUPPLIER.S_NATIONKEY)> x)

loop 

dbms_output.put_line ('R_NAME' || chr(18) || 'N_NAME' || chr(18) || 'COUNT(S_NATIONKEY)' || chr(10));

dbms_output.put_line (QRow.R_NAME || chr(18) || QRow.N_NAME || chr(18) || QRow.counter || chr(10));

end loop;
end;
/
show errors;

execute numberOfSupplier(130);
```

Comment: Have you simply tried to remove those `chr(18)`?

Comment: `CHR(18)` is a non-printable control character. Maybe use `;` or `CHR(9)` for TAB

Comment: It solved by by using `chr(9)` . Thanks both of you Sir.